# Atzeret: Shavuot v.s. Simchat Torah

Tags: commentaries, shavuos, simchat-torah

Both Shemini Atzeret/Simchat Torah as Shavuot are called 'Atzeret', both are about Matan Torah.

In what way are they comparable, and in which way are they different if both celebrate Matan Torah?

Comment: The last days of Sukkot and _Pesach_ are called Atzeret in the Torah. Shavuot is not.

Comment: Shemini Atzeret is not a celebration of Mattan Torah as far as I know

Comment: @DoubleAA In the Mishnah, (Rosh Hashanah 16a) and Gemara (Pesachim 68b) it is called “Atzeret.”  The Targum to Bamidbar 28:26, interprets the word “beshavu’oteichem” — “your Festival of Weeks” — “be’atzrateichon.”

Comment: So maybe Matan Torah itself isn't connected with Shemini Atzeret, but when Simchat Torah is celebrated on the same day there is a celebration of one's own 'Matan Torah' the celebration of us have been given the Torah, accepted it. While ofcourse the tone of these two celebrations is different there seem to be at least some comparingsons possible...

Answer (score 0):

The Dubner Maggid was asked this question. [This is a link to his moshol](http://parsha-story.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/shavuot-appreciating-gift.html).

The bottom line is

> The Maggid of Dubno explained that when the Torah was offered to the
>   world, the nations raised many questions about its contents.
>
> The Jewish people, however, were committed to keeping it, even before
>   understanding everything it contained. "Na'aseh veNishma!" "We will
>   observe and we will understand."
>
> We celebrate this unquestioning acceptance of the Torah on Shavuot.
>
> Yet their promise of total trust was incomplete. The mind can know and
>   decide what the heart is not ready to accept. Only after living with
>   Torah - only after completing a yearly cycle of studying the Torah and
>   experiencing its teachings, as "Its ways are pleasant and all its
>   paths are peace" (Proverbs 3:17) - only then is the Jewish people
>   ready, on Simchat Torah, to express their true joy over God's precious
>   gift.